# How can I stop displaying the SSH exec command in the output console in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

My SSH code runs fine and I get the desired output as well. But, in the output displayed the whole SSH exec command is printed. How can I stop displaying the exec command in output.
I don't want to use scripts as well.

Below is the SSH command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Output:

```
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [#!/bin/bash echo "Hello World"]     
... Hello World
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
```

I want to remove the SSH exec command and display only the output of the SSH exec command.

Comment: What SSH code? What SSH command are you talking about?. Please, give more details so people will be able to help you better.

Comment: Below is the SSH command I used:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"

Comment: and I got this output:
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [#!/bin/bash echo "Hello World"] ... 
Hello World

SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using a build step of type "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh". I don't see a way to reduce the verbosity of that type of build step. But what about just doing an ssh command in an "Execute shell" build step:

```
ssh other_machine 'bash +x -c "echo Hello World"'
```

which results in:

```
Started by user Eric Pyle
Building remotely on slavex in workspace /home/test/hudson/workspace/eric_test
[eric_test] $ sh -xe C:\cygwin64\tmp\hudson6477425368203901178.sh
+ ssh other_machine 'bash +x -c "echo Hello World"'
Hello World
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Note that we have configured passwordless ssh to `other_machine` in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 13th 2018 the Jenkins SSH Plugin version 2.6.1 supports hiding the ssh command from job Console output - you can configure it in job's configuration page.
HTH